# Add time delay for executing multiple dll's from VSTEST plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, vstest

I am trying to execute multiple dlls in jenkins using the VSTESTRunner plugin. Currently it is launching all the dlls at same time which causes an issue in how the output folders are created.

Is there a way to add a time delay of say 10 seconds between each dll?

I have tried adding the plugin multiple times into the jenkins job configuration but then it executes dlls in a series, but i want to execute the dlls in parallel.

Any thoughts if this is possible in jenkins?